# Que signifie « sur ce » ?

Tags: expressions, oral

Je viens d'apprendre la phrase « Sur ce, je dois aller » pour conversation.  Ma prof. explique : « Sur ce = Sur ces dernières paroles. »  Je regrette, je ne comprends toujours pas.

Est-ce  la même chose que : « Enfin bref » ?
Comment dit-on « sur ce » en anglais ? Est-ce « And now » ou « Finally » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« Sur ce » veut effectivement dire « Sur ces dernières paroles ». On trouve cette expression par exemple lorsque l'on est en train de discuter avec un ami, et l'on s’aperçoit que l'on va être en retard pour aller à un rendez-vous:

> Sur ce, je dois partir car je vais être en retard.

C'est une manière de terminer poliment la conversation. La traduction dans ce cas serait plutôt « And now, I must leave as I'm going to be late ».

Answer (score 5):

We say "*sur ce*" or "*sur quoi*". And English has what I think is the exact equivalent: "upon which"<sup>*</sup>.

But your choice of "and now" is quite good as well. I would not use "finally" because "sur ce"/ "sur quoi" doesn't imply that whatever you were talking about is finished, the conversation could be resumed next time you meet. It just means the conversation has to end because whoever's speaking has to put an end to it.

<sup>* "Whereupon" would do nicely as well, maybe in a more literary context.</sup>

Comment: Je distinguerais « sur ce » et « sur quoi » : j’emploierais le premier pour me référer à des paroles (« sur ces mots »), le second pour des évènements (« suite à quoi », qui correspond d’après moi mieux à « *whereupon* »).

Comment: « *upon which* », ça correspond à « sur quoi ». Je ne vois pas d'équivalent exact à « sur ce », d'autres réponses ont fait des propositions.

Comment: @Gilles: *hereupon* ? (en tant que traduction littérale je pense que ça marche assez bien)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez “Sur ce” est surtout utilisé en début de phrase. “Hereupon”, au contraire, s'utilise plutôt en milieu de phrase.

Comment: @Gilles: [Je ne crois pas](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hereupon%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en), le principal problème étant plutôt qu'il s'agit d'un mot déjà oublié au siècle dernier.

Answer (score 2):

Ta prof a raison car la définition littérale/sémantique de « Sur ce » est « Sur ces dernières paroles ». Mais le sens à donner à l'expression est: « Après avoir dit ça,... ». Le sens peut aussi être « Enfin bref » si tu ne veux plus continuer à discuter du sujet.

En anglais, ça pourrait être "You know what, I'm leaving/I have to go."

Or as Jeremy Clarkson from *Top Gear* likes to say :

> “On that bombshell”

Answer (score 1):

Le piège réside ici dans **la préposition *« sur »*** qui **n'a pas son sens spatial, plus courant**, mais le sens de la préposition *après*, avec la nuance : *juste après*. Personne n'a dit que c'était d'une grande logique, en effet. Les prépositions sont une source infinie de ces petites exceptions...

Mais en connaissance du fait, l'expression devient plus claire, très voisine de la variante *Après ceci / Après quoi* (voisine mais cependant avec des cas d'utilisation et un registre de langage légèrement différents), comme l'indiquent déjà nombre d'excellentes réponses.

Pour l'équivalent anglais, je proposerais plutôt ***With that, ...***

Answer (score 1):

En anglais, je pense que la traduction la plus plausible de

> Sur ce, je dois y aller

serait

> Well, i've got to go

mais il est vrai qu'on peut utiliser quelque chose de moins direct comme «

> On that note, ..
>
> So saying, ...

Or

> With this, ...

Answer (score 1):

My vote is: "With that,... " often followed by an explanatory phrase e.g. "I need to leave*."

The expression is typically spoken by someone who is (believes they are) controlling the conversation (e.g. a Professor speaking to a student) as an assertive way to end a discussion he/she believes has been discussed 'enough'.